# .Net Setup project warning

Tags: winforms, setup-project

I have a setup project to install a Windows Forms application. When I build this setup project, I get a warning that says:

> WARNING: The version of the .NET Framework launch condition '.NET Framework 3.5' does not match the selected .NET Framework bootstrapper package. Update the .NET Framework launch condition to match the version of the .NET Framework selected in the Prerequisites Dialog Box.

I can see in the launch conditions window that .Net Framework 3.5 is selected

[image: image description]

Then when I go see the prerequisites window Net Framework 3.5 SP1 is selected.

[image: Prerequisits window]

What can I do to get ride of this message, the launch window dropdown does not contain 3.5 SP1 and the prerequisites window list does not contain 3.5 without sp1?

Thanks to you all!

Comment: Had some trouble getting a repro, this issue is specific to VS2010.  Just set it to "Any", the prerequisite already makes sure that .NET will be present.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create a custom prerequisite for .NET Framework 3.5. Visual Studio setup projects do not support custom prerequisite creation. However, it can be done by manually generating the required manifests.

You can find the manifests structure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(VS.80).aspx

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) tool.

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

You can then select the custom prerequisite in your setup project Properties page.

Another solution would be to remove the launch condition completely and use just the prerequisite.